# Link only specific text in a node

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have the following sample XML:

```
<block>
    <see link="IDNUMBER-1">(<i>See:</i> IDNUMBER-1</see>; <see link="IDNUMBER-2"> IDNUMBER-2)</see>
    <see link="IDNUMBER-3">(<i>See:</i> IDNUMBER-3)</see>
</block>
```

I am supposed to link these `<see>` elements to their respective pages, *but only* the IDNUMBER text - in other words, the "See:" part as well as the paranthesis should not be clickable at all.

The good part is that the `link` attribute is always the same as the text that needs to be clickable.

So far I have this code:

```
<xsl:template match="see">
    <a>
       <xsl:attribute name="href">
           <xsl:value-of select="concat('#', @link)"/>
       </xsl:attribute>      
       <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </a>
</xsl:template>
```

And while this is "correct", it renders the whole thing clickable. Any way I could somehow instruct XSLT to exclude the "See:" part, or make it so that it initially makes only the `link` attribute (that is, its relevant text) clickable?

**EDIT**: XSLT version 1.1

Comment: What version of XSLT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do, instead of matching on **see**, match on its text nodes, but only where the text contains the **link** attribute

```
<xsl:template match="see/text()[contains(., ../@link)]">
```

This means it won't match text nodes that just contain a single parenthesis, for example.

However, it will obviously match the text node "IDNUMBER-2)", but you could use the **substring-before** and **substring-after** functions to output these either side of the link.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="see/text()[contains(., ../@link)]">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., ../@link)" />
        <a href="#{../@link}">
           <xsl:value-of select="../@link" />
        </a>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., ../@link)" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the use of Attribute Value Templates in outputing the **href** attribute here. The curly braces indicate an expression to be evaluated, rather than output literally, and makes the code much more concise and readable.

Comment: Thank you Tim. Once again, you replied to my question and once again it is the correct answer.